# How to set allowed function or method in ejs?

Tags: node.js, ejs

I need to set ejs template engine to transpile ejs code to only allow specific function.

let's say i create 2 function. i want to allow hello function only, and javascript reserved keyword like for, while, and so on. nodejs module not allowed to access without my permission.

```
function hello(){
  return 'hello'
}

function world(){
  return 'world'
}
```

in ejs views, index.

```
<h1><%- hello() %></h1> // output hello
<h1><%- world() %></h1> // i want it empty string or custom information that tell this function not allowed.
```

Comment: So don't pass `world()` to the template renderer.

Comment: @robertklep but i can access javascript library. like console and so on `<% console.log('nodejs module') %>`. the other one if i expose to end user. user can create function that do heavy task in backend.

Comment: [_"You should never give end-users unfettered access to the EJS render method, If you do so you are using EJS in an inherently un-secure way."_](https://github.com/mde/ejs#important). In other words: `ejs` isn't meant to be used in the way you intend to use it.